# Find Value of Specific Key in Nested Map

Tags: clojure, hashmap

In Clojure, how can I find the value of a key that may be deep in a nested map structure? For example:

```
(def m {:a {:b "b"
            :c "c"
            :d {:e "e"
                :f "f"}}})

(find-nested m :f)

=> "f"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Clojure offers [`tree-seq`](http://conj.io/store/v0/org.clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clj/clojure.core/tree-seq) to do a depth-first traversal of any value. This will simplify the logic needed to find your nested key:

```
(defn find-nested
  [m k]
  (->> (tree-seq map? vals m)
       (filter map?)
       (some k)))

(find-nested {:a {:b {:c 1}, :d 2}} :c)
;; => 1
```

Also, finding all matches becomes a matter of replacing `some` with `keep`:

```
(defn find-all-nested
  [m k]
  (->> (tree-seq map? vals m)
       (filter map?)
       (keep k)))

(find-all-nested {:a {:b {:c 1}, :c 2}} :c)
;; => [2 1]
```

Note that maps with `nil` values might require some special treatment.

---

**Update:** If you look at the code above, you can see that `k` can actually be a function which offers a lot more possibilities:

- to find a string key:

  ```
  (find-nested m #(get % "k"))
  ```
- to find multiple keys:

  ```
  (find-nested m #(some % [:a :b]))
  ```
- to find only positive values in maps of integers:

  ```
  (find-nested m #(when (some-> % :k pos?) (:k %)))
  ```

Comment: This is a good one. How would you describe the general use case for `tree-seq`? I feel like I hear a lot of people saying not to use it. Is it simply used for turning a tree into a seq as the name might suggest? Is there a better explanation?

Comment: I think I have never used it in a production context but I can't really see how someone would argue against it since the function is relatively simple and good at what it does - most of the solutions in other answers actually re-implement the logic that `tree-seq` offers. And regarding a summary: yes, `tree-seq` turns a tree into a (lazy!) seq by listing the nodes in the order they would be visited during depth-first search.

Comment: I updated the answer with some more examples, including the lookup of string keys.

Comment: I think this is a good solution when you don't know the structure of the map and need to search it to find a specific key. If you do know the structure of the map i.e. you know the path to the node if it exists, then you should use get-in rather than perform a tree traversal. This could be what people mean when they say don't use tree-seq. However, when you don't know where in the map the key might be, some form of traversal and search is required and you may as well use tree-seq rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: In Cljs, `some` does not work for keys that are strings. E.g. `(some "k" {"k" 1})` => `pred.call is not a function in cljs`.

Comment: @pate This was already mentioned in one of the previous comments - I then added some examples to the answer that demonstrate usage of other lookup functions, specifically: `(find-nested m #(get % "k"))`.

Answer (score 10):

If you know the nested path then use get-in.

```
=> (get-in m [:a :d :f])
=> "f"
```

See here for details: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in

If you don't know the path in your nested structure you could write a function that recurses through the nested map looking for the particular key in question and either returns its value when it finds the first one or returns all the values for :f in a seq.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the "path", consider using [get-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in):

```
(get-in m [:a :d :f]) ; => "f"
```

If the "path" is unknown you can use something like next function:

```
(defn find-in [m k]
  (if (map? m)
    (let [v (m k)]
      (->> m
           vals
           (map #(find-in % k)) ; Search in "child" maps
           (cons v) ; Add result from current level
           (filter (complement nil?))
           first))))

(find-in m :f) ; "f"
(find-in m :d) ; {:e "e", :f "f"}
```

Note: given function will find only the first occurrence.

Comment: I do not know the path. I will look in to the function you give

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that will find the key without knowing the path to it. If there are multiple matching keys, only one will be returned:

```
(defn find-key [m k]
  (loop [m' m]
    (when (seq m')
      (if-let [v (get m' k)]
        v
        (recur (reduce merge
                       (map (fn [[_ v]]
                              (when (map? v) v))
                            m')))))))
```

If you require all values you can use:

```
(defn merge-map-vals [m]
  (reduce (partial merge-with vector)
          (map (fn [[_ v]]
                 (when (map? v) v))
               m)))

(defn find-key [m k]
  (flatten
   (nfirst
    (drop-while first
                (iterate (fn [[m' acc]]
                           (if (seq m')
                             (if-let [v (get m' k)]
                               [(merge-map-vals m') (conj acc v)]
                               [(merge-map-vals m') acc])
                             [nil acc]))
                         [m []])))))
```