# Iterate Nested map in Clojure and get all values where key is :depth

Tags: clojure

I need to iterate Nested map in Clojure and get all values where key is :depth. I tried to use clojure.walk but I don't understand how it works exactly.

```
(w/walk identity identity {:a 1 :b 2 :depth 3 :g {:i 90 :depth 22}})
```

It would be great to see some working examples.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @cfrick I added, but this is rubbish anyways as I don't understand how it works...

Comment: Walking is not that great to extract data.  I think you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064875/decompose-nested-maps-into-key-value-pairs

Comment: More prior art: [Iterate over all keys of nested map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32853004/625403)

Comment: The find-all-nested function in the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091305/find-value-of-specific-key-in-nested-map looks like a solution